# custom type declaration taking function C++

Tags: c++

I want to make something like below

```
void func1(int x)
{
    ...
}

int main()
{
   auto acceptorFunc = bind(func1, 1);
   keyword acceptorFunc;
   return 0;
}
```

keyword is a struct which takes any function call as argument and execute its operator().

```
struct keyword
{
...
void operator()
{
     // do some thing
        acceptorFunc(x);
    // do something
}
}
```

I donot understand what kind of declaration is "keywordacceptorFunc".

example usage that um planning to make is below

```
int main(){
    auto f = bind(func1, 1);
    TIMEOUT f;
}
```

This will execute func1 but will wait for 1 second before and after executing func1.

Comment: Would you settle for `TIMEOUT(f)` syntax? That's rather trivial to arrange.

Comment: no i know how to do TIMEOUT(f). I am looking for a solution which would be TIMEOUT<space>f.

Comment: I am inspired by usage:

co_await std::chrono::seconds(1 + rand() % 5)
     
i want my keyword to behave like the co_await expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
struct TimeoutExecutor {
  template <typename F>
  void operator=(F f) {
      // Do something before
      f();
      // Do something after
  }
};

#define TIMEOUT TimeoutExecutor{} =
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6cs36d) . Actually, any binary operator would work, doesn't need to be an assignment.

Comment: this answer is what i am looking for *thumbs up* thanks. But just out of curiosity is there any other way to do it without the use of macro ?

Comment: No, I don't think so. At least, I can't think of any.